# Defined service method is not called, instead real service's is called

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am following [this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/UDB-jm8MWro) and its source is [here](https://github.com/lavinjj/diy-brew-controller).

I am trying to apply [this test](https://github.com/lavinjj/diy-brew-controller/blob/master/test/spec/controllers/main.js)

Here is my test

```
describe("InStudentController", function () {
    beforeEach(module("eucngts"));
    var inStudentsController;
    var MyInStudentsService;

    var $scope;
    var $q;
    var deferred;
    beforeEach(function () {

        MyInStudentsService =
            {
                getInStudents: function () {
                    deferred = $q.defer();
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            };
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _$q_) {
        $q = _$q_; 
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        inStudentsController = $controller('InStudentsController', {
            service: MyInStudentsService 
        });
    }));
    it("should request list of inStudents", function () {
        spyOn(MyInStudentsService, "getInStudents").and.callThrough();
        inStudentsController.getPage(); // <-- HERE
        //deferred.resolve();
        $scope.$root.$digest();  
        expect(MyInStudentsService.getInStudents).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Here is relevant controller code:

```
            InStudentsController.prototype.getPage = function (criteria) {
                var self = this;
                self.showGrid = true;
                self.service.getInStudents();  

            };
```

When I call **getPage()** on test it calls real service method instead of defined in test.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

I don't use scope in my controller here is generated code(I use typescript):

```
function InStudentsController (service) {
        var self = this;
        self.service = service; 
    }

InStudentsController.$inject = ['InStudentsService'];
angular.module("eucngts").controller("InStudentsController", InStudentsController);
```

Comment: Can you show declaration of `InStudentsController`?

Comment: Something seems to be missing. In `beforeEach` a new scope is created but not injected. Actually if `InStudentsController` expects `$scope` this code should simply crash

Comment: @KirillSlatin I don't use $scope in my controller

Comment: Small remark. In presented code there is no use of mocking `getInStudents` with a function that returns a dummy promise. It can easily be a noop since controller doesn't use the return value. I understand real code is more complicated, but perhaps this may be applied in the real code you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your latest update it is clear that the name of dependency is used wrong in the test. It must be `InStudentsService` instead of `service`. When using `$inject` property of controller constructor only that name matters, not the formal parameter name in function. That makes minification possible

```
  inStudentsController = $controller('InStudentsController', {
        InStudentsService: MyInStudentsService 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kirill, I was on the issue since a couple days, finally resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're not injecting a scope into the controller. I think this:

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
inStudentsController = $controller('InStudentsController', {
    service: MyInStudentsService 
});
```

Should be this:

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
$scope.service = MyInStudentsService
inStudentsController = $controller('InStudentsController', {
    $scope: $scope
});
```

But it seems odd passing the service in on the scope. Instead, you should be declaring the controller something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('InStudentsController', function ($scope, InStudentsService) {
...
  });
```

And then the service would be injected like so:

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
inStudentsController = $controller('InStudentsController', {
    $scope: $scope,
    InStudentsService: MyInStudentsService
});
```